# How to enumerate keys of a 'reactive', in Vue.js Composition API?

Tags: vuejs3

I declare the state like this:

```
const symbols = reactive( new Map() );
```

The keys are dynamic (this shadows a database table), added by `symbols.set(id, {...})` and removed by `symbols.delete(id)`.

How should I iterate over the `reactive`'s keys & values? Have tried this, and I always just get an empty iterator:

```
    const symbolsByLayer = computed(() => {
      console.debug("New stuff!", symbols);   // This shows '[[Target]]' with two entries

      console.debug( Array.from(symbols.entries()) );   // Array(0)
      console.debug( Array.from(symbols.keys()) );   // Array(0)
      console.debug(Object.entries(symbols));   // Array(0)
```

I haven't found a doc mentioning use of `reactive` with dynamic keys, but I presume it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this:

```
const symbolsSortedByLayer = computed(() => {   // () => [ {...symbolsD, _id: index } ]   // sorted by layer

  const arr = Array.from(symbols.entries(), ([id,o]) => ({ ...o, _id: id }) );    // add '_id' to all entries
  const arr2 = arr.sort( (a,b) => a.layer ?? Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY - b.layer ?? Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY );

  console.log("Array of symbols (sorted): ", arr2);
  return arr2;
});
```

Still no idea why the code in the question was giving empty arrays. Leaving here, in case someone can point it out.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's too late, but in case someone else has same problem:

`reactive` is used internally as `Proxy` object, so you can't interact with it directly as with normal object.

You can use [toRaw](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#toraw) function to convert reactive object back to normal object, to perform operations on it. But keep in mind that this "normal object" will lose reactive characteristics.